# ElementNotVisibleException on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium2.2.0(jar) + JPype + Python.
My IE version is IE 8.
The same code works fine with FireFox.

This is the whole exception that I am getting.

-- driver.findElementById("clinician_submit").click()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
jpype._jexception.org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverExceptionPyRaisable: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Build info: version: '2.2.0', revision: '13073', time: '2011-07-25 19:23:01'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_26'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

Answer (score 1):

The classic reason for that is the **MSIE zoom level is set to other value than 100%**.